Python Polars recursion
I've used Polars for some time now but this is something that often makes me go from Polars DataFrames to native Python calculations. I've spent resonable time looking for solutions that (tries) to use shift(), rolling(), group_by_dynamic() and so on but none is successful.
Task
Do calculation that depends on previous calculation's result that is in the same column.
Example in Excel
In Excel this is like the most straighforward formula ever...if the "index" is zero I want to return "A", otherwise I want to return the result from the cell above.




A
B
C




1
Index
Result
Formula for the "Result" column


2
0
A
=IF(A2=0;"A";B1)


3
1
A
=IF(A3=0;"A";B2)



Where is the recursion
In column "B" the formula refers to the previously calculated values on the same column "B".

Copy & Paste Excel's solution to Polars
# Import Polars module.
import polars as pl

# Create the data.
data = {'Index': [0, 1]}

# Create the DataFrame.
df = pl.from_dict(data)

# Add a column to the DataFrame.
df = df.with_columns(

    # Tries to reproduce the Excel formula.
    Result = pl.when(
        pl.col('Index') == 0
    ).then(
        pl.lit('A')
    ).otherwise(
        pl.col('Result')
    )

)

The issue
Within the "with_columns()" method the "Result" column cannot be referred because It doens't exist in the DataFrame yet. If we try to do so, we get a ColumnNotFoundError:

Question
Any idea on how can I accomplish such a simple task on Polars?
Thank you,

Note: in the "Example in Excel" the table was well formatted when editing the question...not sure why it lost formatting when posting the question.

Yeah, the issue was the lack of a newline before the markdown table - but it renders correctly in the preview. Not sure if that would be considered a "bug" or not.

One name for this is a "vertical scan": https://github.com/pola-rs/polars/issues/12165 - Generally, one would need to implement it in Rust as a Polars Plugin: https://marcogorelli.github.io/polars-plugins-tutorial/cum_sum/


How can I do a calculation that depends on previous (row's) calculation result that is in the same column?

The short answer is that you can't without falling back into Python.
To do this, any library would need to essentially need to iterate over the rows, only calculating a single row at a time. This means any sort of vectorisation is not possible.
Polars offers map_elements for this use-case, but it is discouraged. From the docs:

This method is much slower than the native expressions API. Only use it if you cannot implement your logic otherwise.

df = pl.DataFrame({'Index': [1, 0, 1, 1, 0]})


previous_result = "Result" # hardcode the header as the intial "previous result"
def f(index):
    global previous_result
    out = "A" if index == 0 else previous_result
    previous_result = out
    return out

print(df.with_columns(Result=pl.col("Index").map_elements(f, return_dtype=pl.String)))
# shape: (5, 2)
# ┌───────┬────────┐
# │ Index ┆ Result │
# │ ---   ┆ ---    │
# │ i64   ┆ str    │
# ╞═══════╪════════╡
# │ 1     ┆ Result │
# │ 0     ┆ A      │
# │ 1     ┆ A      │
# │ 1     ┆ A      │
# │ 0     ┆ A      │
# └───────┴────────┘

The better solution is to attempt to recognise any pattern that allows the computation to be done in a vectorised way. In this (likely contrived) example, it is that once Index == 0 has been seen once, the result of the remainder of the column is "A"
df.with_columns(
    # If the row number is >= to the first row an index of 0 was seen
    pl.when(pl.int_range(pl.len()) >= pl.arg_where(pl.col("Index") == 0).min())
    .then(pl.lit("A"))
    .otherwise(pl.lit("Result"))
    .alias("Result")
)
# Returns the same output as above


As in your case it's not really complicated recursion you could use pl.Expr.forward_fill() as simple approximation of recursion.

pl.when() to identify rows with Index = 0.
pl.Expr.forward_fill() to fill rows after with the same value.
pl.Expr.fill_null() to fill empty part with a fallback Result value.

df.with_columns(
    pl.when(pl.col.Index == 0).then(pl.lit("A"))
    .forward_fill()
    .fill_null("Result")
    .alias("Result")
)

shape: (5, 2)
┌───────┬────────┐
│ Index ┆ Result │
│ ---   ┆ ---    │
│ i64   ┆ str    │
╞═══════╪════════╡
│ 1     ┆ Result │
│ 0     ┆ A      │
│ 1     ┆ A      │
│ 1     ┆ A      │
│ 0     ┆ A      │
└───────┴────────┘


Nice solution. I think it is a bit more intuitive / elegant than mine.
